# JQuery FadeIn - Fade in the background image div but not the contents div?

Tags: jquery, background, fadein, fade, onload

I'm having a hell of a time trying to figure out how to do this:

See http://webid3.feckcorp.com for a live example of the problem.

I'd like to use JQuery to fade in `<div id="home_page_back">` (contains the vertically lined gray background behind the main contents), but not fade in the contents in front of it that are included in `<div id="content" class="container">`.

Right now, I can only seem to make it fade **everything** in, whereas I only want the background div to fade in.

Anyone who can shed some light on the solution and help me out it'd be much appreciated.

Cheers

**SOLVED**

I adjusted the z-index of the div to −1 and positioned it absolutely. Simple as this:

```
z-index:-1;
position:absolute;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652281/jquery-fade-in-background-colour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think something like this should work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#home_page_back").hide();
$("#content").fadeTo(0, 0);
$("#home_page_back").fadeIn(500, function(){
    $("#content").fadeTo(500, 1);
    });     
});
```

You could also use `$("#content").hide();`, but like this you'll probably get a smoother fade when you need to show `#content`.

Comment: I tried this, but it made the entire content including the background image hidden? Check out the web address in the OP to see what happened. Please advise

Comment: I've tried making a new piece of code, but i'm not sure if this is what you wanted?..

Comment: Kristoffer, I'd definitely prefer to use your method seeing that it seems to be the easiest rather than having to reorganize everything in CSS, but it doesn't seem to be working for me. When I exchanged the css('opacity', '0') with hide() it just completely hide all the content and the background. If you have any other solutions, I'd happily try them out!!

Comment: Ah I'm sorry, I didn't see that you edited the original code. Just tried it - it looks much better than before but I'm really looking to make the content div not fade at all and just appear immediately - then have the home_page_back div fade in behind

Comment: Okay, in that case i don't really have a solution, since the content div is part of home_page_back, it can not be visible while home_page_back is hidden... You might want to look for a solution to fade in the background image though, like in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/977090/jquery-fade-in-background-image Or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408761/jquery-fadeout-fadein-background-image-on-hover

Comment: No problem, I solved it myself by adding a z-index and positing to CSS. I marked your answers as my selected solution because it came closest to what I needed and you worked the hardest on it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You have Just 2 Choices:
1- To put the `content` div outside `home_page_back`
2- Use the css3 rule:  `background-color: rgba(255,0,0,1);` for the `content` div

By the way, this is a pure css problem not jquery problem, which is any transparent element will get all its children elements to be the same transparent.

CSS3 solved this problem by using the [rgba color](http://www.google.com/webhp?rlz=1C1CHKZ_enEG430EG430&sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1&nord=1#sclient=psy&hl=en&rlz=1C1CHKZ_enEG430EG430&nord=1&site=webhp&source=hp&q=background-color%20rgba&aq=0&aqi=g5&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=a17560d1ef61d5f5&biw=1366&bih=643&ion=1&ion=1&pf=p&pdl=300) in which you can play with the last value of it to control the opacity, and it will not affect the inner elements.

And you can check for many solutions around these 2 way [on google](http://www.google.com/webhp?rlz=1C1CHKZ_enEG430EG430&sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1&nord=1#sclient=psy&hl=en&rlz=1C1CHKZ_enEG430EG430&nord=1&site=webhp&source=hp&q=css%20transparent%20child&aq=f&aqi=g-j3&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=a17560d1ef61d5f5&ion=1&biw=1366&bih=643) first search results.

Twitter is using this CSS3
[image]

**Update:**
It seams that RGBA is not supported by jquery so may be you will need a [plugin](http://pioupioum.fr/sandbox/jquery-color/) for that, or simply create a class in css and give it to that parent element.

Comment: I tried using Solution #2 but it did not change the fadein - the content still faded in. I guess you found out that RGBA doesn't work with JQuery. Oh well..

Answer (score 0):

Since `#content` is a child of `#home_page_back`, fading in the parent will naturally fade in all the children. Consider extracting the `#home_page_back` div and putting it as a sibling of `#content`. You can still get the dimensions you need via CSS.

Comment: I attempted doing this quickly, but it still didn't seem to work oddly. I put #home_page_back as a child of #content but it still faded both the content and child (as well as made the background smaller.. which of course can be changed via CSS)